# Consolidate/Merge Duplicate Records into one

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I have an access table containing over 100,000 records.  My problem is that many of the records have duplicate information.  I would like to merge/combine the records into record.

I have a field (CommonField) that can be used to identify the duplicates (sometimes more than two records).  Each field needs to be considered on an individual basis.  For instance:

If the date fields are not equal, I would prefer to keep the most recent date.

If the count fields are not equal, I would prefer to keep the larger value.

If the company names are not equal, I would prefer to keep both names unless one is within the other.

[CLICK HERE](http://thepoolscene.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/StackOverflow.xlsx) for a sample of the data:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| Existing Records |             |       |       |                  |           |            |        |                             |
+------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| ID               | CommonField | First | Last  | Email            | Date      | Currency   | Count  | Company                     |
| 1                | AA123       | John  |       |                  |           | $465,000   |        | ABC Company Ltd             |
| 2                | AA123       | John  |       | John@gmail.com   | 1-Mar-78  | $465,000   | 87,000 | ABC Company                 |
| 3                | AA123       |       | Doe   |                  | 14-Mar-78 | $465,000   | 88,000 |                             |
| 4                | BB456       | Dave  | Smith |                  | 1-Apr-92  | $1,200,000 | 5,000  | Carter Company              |
| 5                | BB456       |       | Smith | Dave@aol.com     | 1-Apr-92  | $1,200,000 | 5,000  | Simpson Ltd                 |
| 6                | CC568       |       |       | Jane@hotmail.com | 1-Sep-05  | $60,000    |        | Woods Holdings              |
| 7                | CC568       |       | Woods | Jane@hotmail.com |           |            | 40,000 | Woods                       |
| 8                | CC568       | Jane  | Woods |                  | 1-Sep-05  |            |        |                             |
| 9                | DD211       | Bob   | Burns | Bob@gmail.com    | 5-Aug-01  | $678,100   | 21,400 |                             |
|                  |             |       |       |                  |           |            |        |                             |
| Desired Result   |             |       |       |                  |           |            |        |                             |
| ID               | CommonField | First | Last  | Email            | Date      | Currency   | Count  | Company                     |
| 10               | AA123       | John  | Doe   | John@gmail.com   | 14-Mar-78 | $465,000   | 88,000 | ABC Company Ltd             |
| 11               | BB456       | Dave  | Smith | Dave@aol.com     | 1-Apr-92  | $1,200,000 | 5,000  | Carter Company, Simpson Ltd |
| 12               | CC568       | Jane  | Woods | Jane@hotmail.com | 1-Sep-05  | $60,000    | 40,000 | Woods Holdings              |
| 13               | DD211       | Bob   | Burns | Bob@gmail.com    | 5-Aug-01  | $678,100   | 21,400 |                             |
+------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

I am interested in hearing your suggestions as to the best way of tackling this project.

Comment: The OP is explicitly about Access so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly.

I think for the name fields, you may need another table to combine names.  I'd start by making a new table from a group by query on both the common id and the company name.  Add an extra field for the standardized name to the table, then use a find duplicates query to look at all the common ids with more than one name and manually assign a standardized name.

Then you can bring both the original data table and the company names table into a group by query and pull the standardized name into the final result.  For the data and count fields, you can use max(date) and max(count).  This should work for the first, last and email text fields also - but you will want to manually examine the results pretty carefully.